# Kuberentes AWS cloud provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I would like to ask your help , what is the best way to enable cloud-provider aws , I am using kubespray to initate the clusters
but always when I got cloud provider to aws is failing so I try to set it up manually after
https://cloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io/getting_started/

https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/issues/258

then , I did the following

```
adding --cloud-provider=external to both static pods of kube-api and the controller
/etc/kubernetes/manifests# grep cloud *
kube-apiserver.yaml:    - --cloud-provider=external
kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --configure-cloud-routes=false
kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --cloud-provider=external
```

adding it to kubelet

```
kubelet.env:--cloud-provider=external \
```

applied the manifest , with the image modfied to

```
**gcr.io/k8s-staging-provider-aws/cloud-controller-manager:v20210510-v1.21.0-alpha.0**
```

to be sure I rebooted although not required
I have always the

```
aws-cloud-controller-manager-kbjwb 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 16 34m (edited) 

cloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.iocloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io
```

Getting Started - Kubernetes AWS Cloud Provider
Documentation for AWS Cloud Provider for Kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable connectivity with AWS with the help of an access key or the secret id? You can also call these using environment variables dynamically using Hashicorp Vault.